# What will happen on day 90 of Lifehacks public beta?

Tags: discussion

Now Lifehacks is 88 days in public beta and it will soon reach 90 days. In Area51 it is written "Sites remain in beta for at least 90 days to build up a critical mass of users, questions, and participation.".

What is going to happen on the 90th day?

Comment: It will explode! Make sure you clear your browser cache before it happens to safeguard your computer.

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely nothing.

90 days is the earliest a site is considered for graduation. [As you can see](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta), many sites take a lot longer than that — some have been in beta for years. (In fact, very few sites graduated around the 90-day mark; I think only one graduated before that.)

Comment: Yeah, my main site (Gardening & Landscaping) has been in beta for over 3 years now.

Comment: @J.Musser Shouldn't the diamond change which is your main site? jk :p

Answer (score 6):

I doubt we'll graduate for a while yet. Ninety days is just the bare minimum.

I've been told we may get some moderators though...

Comment: I was thinking if we are expecting any changes after this period

Comment: @vladiz Nothing is certain. At some point privileges will become higher rep requirements.